# Fill a Content Page dynamically - Cardbox views?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to fill a content view dynamically, Meaning I am not sure if I will have 1 element or 500.

When I fill it, I need to be able to individually click any of them and recognize which one it is. Tried few methods and I failed so far. Some stuff doesn't work on all 3 OS (Win, Android and iOS).

Each element needs to have 3 divisions (text + image + price) and the view has to be scroll-able.

[What i am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77DCy.png)

Can you please point me in the right direction? Already tried the SintaxIsMyUI examples.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no out of the box control in Xamarin.Forms that could help you implement your requirements.

You may want to use [Collection View](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_collection_views/) in iOS, [RecyclerView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/) in Android and [ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) on Windows Phone

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was hoping to avoid custom renders since all my project code works on all platforms at once (ok, maybe some stuff is platform related with #if __MOBILE__ and stuff).. Learning this so late in the project will be a pain.

Comment: Damn, submitted before i could finish.

I will take a look, thanks alot for your input!